# How to get the Userb first message to me ? This below code helps to get the latest message.I want the first message of that user to me

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

How to get the Userb first message to me ?
This below code helps to get the latest message.
I want the first message of that user to me .

user a is ME 
user b is other user

We want the first  message sent by the user b to user a

My code gets the userb latest message.

New to pythoon coding 
Any suggestions?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from apiclient import errors
import base64
import email
from pampy import match, _
# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'


def main():
"""Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
Lists the user's Gmail labels.
"""
# The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
store = file.Storage('token.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
#print(service.users().execute())

# Call the Gmail API
results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
#print(results)
labels = results.get('labels', [])

if not labels:
    print('No labels found.')
else:
    print('Labels:')
    for label in labels:
        print(label['name'])
response = service.users().messages().list(userId='usera@gmail.com',
                                           q='from:userb@gmail.com').execute()
#print(response['messages'])
#print(response)
messages = []
if 'messages' in response:
    messages.extend(response['messages'])

while 'nextPageToken' in response:
    page_token = response['nextPageToken']
    response = service.users().messages().list(userId='usera@gmail.com', q='from:userb@gmail.com',
                                      pageToken=page_token).execute()
    messages.extend(response['messages'])




message = service.users().messages().get(userId='usera@gmail.com', id=messages[0]['id'],
                                         format='raw').execute()

print('Message snippet: %s' % message['snippet'])
#print(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII')))

msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))

mime_msg = email.message_from_string(str(msg_str))

print(mime_msg)





if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Try changing from messages[0][’id’] to messages[-1][’id’]

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be searching for messages using

```
response = service.users().messages().list(userId='usera@gmail.com',
                                           q='from:userb@gmail.com',
                                           pageToken=page_token).execute()
```

which is correct. This should be returning all of the messages to a from b (after your loop finishes).

However if you check the API documentation for [messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) and the [search syntax](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190) you will notice that there is no way to sort these messages.  In order to find the last one you must download them all and then sort them locally on your machine. You can minimize the requested data by using the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/performance#partial-response) parameter, and then request the full content of only the desired message.